# Saving textarea contents to mysql then displaying correctly on page

Tags: php, mysql, forms, textarea

I am trying to save the contents of a textarea into a mysql database, then echo the contents on the page at a later time.

Here is what Im doing:

In the textarea, I literally type:

```
Hello

How's life?
```

To store it in mysql, I am using:

```
$textarea = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['textarea']);
```

In mysql, it looks like:

```
Hello\r\n\r\nHow\\\'s life?
```

To echo onto the page, I am using:

```
echo nl2br($textarea);
```

But, it is still echoing out exactly as it is shown in mysql. How do I remove the extra `\`'s from the output and also display the contents on the proper line?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
echo preg_replace('/[\s]+/', ' ', stripslashes($textarea));
```

> [stripslashses](https://www.php.net/stripslashes) returns a string with backslashes stripped off.

Comment: If you stripslashes, you are left with a bunch of `rnrn`'s.